# How do I document an object created with Object.create that also has prototypal methods

Tags: javascript, google-closure, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am trying to work out the best way to jsdoc what I have using jsdoc3 with the closure dictionary. The code below documents to almost what I want but the `@class` tag adds a new keyword in the documentation and I am also uneasy about using the class definition as it is not really a class.

```js
/**
 * myObject constructor. <strong> Do not use with new.</strong>
 * @class myObject
 * @param {string} someText The text to store
 */
function myObject (someText) {  
  var instance = Object.create(myObject.prototype);  
  instance.someText = someText;

  return instance;
}

/**
 * Outputs to the console
 */
myObject.prototype.doSomething = function () {
  console.log(this.someText);
};

var test = myObject('foobar');
test.doSomething();
```

`@namespace` seemed like a better pick originally but it does not allow for documenting `@param` or similar on the pseudo constructor. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here demonstrates a possible implementation of your constructor/factory, and how to document members of the constructed object:

```
/**
 * Constructs my object.
 *
 * <p>
 * It is not necessary to call this with <i>new</i> keyword.
 *
 * @name myObject
 * @namespace
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} someText The text to store
 */
function myObject ( someText ) {
    var instance = Object.create( myObject.prototype, {
        /**
         * A member, could be a value of any type.
         *
         * @type {string}
         * @memberof myObject#
         */
        anyMember: {
            value: "whatever"
        },
        /**
         * A <strong>method</strong> member.
         *
         * @param {string|number|object|function} anArgument A parameter.
         *
         * @method
         * @memberof myObject#
         */
        aMethodSpecially: {
            value: function ( anArgument ) {
                throw "Not yet implemented";
            }
        }
    } );

    /**
     * Some text.
     *
     * @property {string}
     */
    instance.someText = someText;

    return instance;
}

/**
 * Outputs to the console.
 *
 * @param {number|string|function|object} someArgument Some method argument.
 * @function doSomething
 * @memberof myObject#
 */
myObject.prototype.doSomething = function ( someArgument ) {
    // @ts-ignore
    console.log( this.someText );
};

var test = myObject( 'foobar' );
test.doSomething();
```

The generated doc using JSDoc 3 looks as follows:
[image]

*--- screenshot continues...*

[image]

Comment: I had jsdocced a factory method with a typedeffed return type but couldn't get prototype method to show up in intellisense. But I had totally missed that # on the end of the @memberof so it works now. Couldn't find an explanation of that hash on usejsdoc though.

Comment: It denotes an instance member

Comment: Ah right, I'm blind, it's right there: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html
It also says you may also use `@memberof something.prototype` instead of `@memberof something#`

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do seems unnecessarily complex. If you want a factory method that constructs/returns a particular type, just make it explicit:

```
/**
 * myObject factory.
 * @param {string} someText
 * @returns {!myObject} The constructed object.
 */
function createMyObject(someText) {  
  return new myObject(someText);
}

/*
 * @param {string} someText The text to store
 * @constructor
 */
function myObject (someText) {  
  this.someText = someText;
}

/**
 * Outputs to the console
 */
myObject.prototype.doSomething = function () {
  console.log(this.someText);
};

var test = createMyObject('foobar');
test.doSomething();
```